# viewing collections of geotif - each part is own layer, it's slow

Tags: qgis

I have ~100 .tif files, making 16GB
Just dropping them into QGIS, shows them as "layers" , but places every correcty , assembling a large map.

The problem is that any panning, zooming causes a full reload (page goes white, then loads images) , browsing is slow.

Is there something I do wrong ? - maybe they should not be considered as different layers, but just parts on one layer ?

Comment: Make a mosaic through GDAL vrt file and perhaps create a few overview levels for the vrt.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to consider when working with large images:

1. Make sure your app caching setting is enabled
2. When viewing many large images it may be better to reference the data locally on your computer rather than over a network directory
3. Convert images to MrSID format if you can, smaller file size to deal with
4. Convert images to a tile cache like .mbtiles